# Fontspec: Is there any practical difference between \setmainfont and \newfontfamily + \def\rmfamily{...}

Tags: fontspec

As the title of this question suggested. Is there any practical difference between

```
\setmainfont{font name}
```

and

```
\newfontfamily\familyname{font name}
\def\rmfamily{\familyname}
```

I had a look into the source of font spec. I believe the above two are practically the same. However, I am still not quite familiar with the latex3 syntax, so I may miss something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually `\rmdefault` should expand to a string representing the font name; with your definition it expands to `\familyname`, whose expansion is *not* a string: for example, with `\newfontfamily\familyname{Hoefler Text}`, the expansion of `\familyname` is `\protect\familyname`  (with a space at the end, as usual with "robusted" commands. The expansion of `\familyname`  is

```
\fontencoding {EU1}\fontfamily {HoeflerText(0)}\selectfont
```

The expansion of `\rmdefault` after `\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}` is

```
HoeflerText(0)
```

So they are quite different.

Also using `\rmfamily` instead of `\rmdefault` does not give equivalent results: first of all, `\rmfamily` should be a robust command; its expansion results in
`\protect\rmfamily`  and then in

```
\not@math@alphabet\rmfamily\mathrm\fontfamily\rmdefault\selectfont
```

So, again, also `\DeclareRobustCommand{\rmfamily}{\familyname}` won't work the same.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. But, what if I use `\def\rmfamily\familyname`? I modified the question.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: N.B. if you *do* want to get access to the NFSS family defined when fontspec loads a new font family, you can use the `\fontspec_set_family:Nnn` command.